# Change users character

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to change the users characters in sprite kit.

I have two views, one with the Play view (the actual game) and the other view to choose a character.

I want the user to choose a character from the character view so in the play view he/she can play with the character selected before.

So I have tried to use NSUserDefaults to save a number depending on the character like this:

```
        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.poolBanner {
            //change to pool ball
            userDefaults.setInteger(1, forKey: "PBChange")
            poolBanner.setScale(0.9)
            print("Pool Ball selected")
        }
        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.tumbleweedBanner {
            //change the character to tumbleweed
            userDefaults.setInteger(2, forKey: "TWChange")
            tumbleweedBanner.setScale(0.9)
            print("Tumbleweed Ball selected")
        }
```

This code is from the character view, when the player select the character they want to use

Now this code is from the play view:

```
    if TWNumber == 2{
        hero.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Tumbleweed")
        hero.size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 57)
    }
    else if PBNumber == 1 {
        hero.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "PoolBall")
        hero.size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)
    }
```

When I tap on to change the character it stays on the same character I have choosed. If I select the poolBall it change the first time and then change it to the tumbleweedBall It will stay the same.

I think that the image are overriding themselves, but I don't know how to ignore the last image if the new is selected...

Comment: you should download the swift book from  ibooks for free and potentially watch some lectures by paul heggarty. Use documentation available in the help tab of xcode. You should watch some youtube vidoes as well to get the basics.  Nsuserdefaults is for saving small peices of data when you quit and restart the app i believe.  Im not an expert either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps:

1. User chooses their character and this code is called:

   ```
   //Enum of possible characters, with their sprite texture names too.
   enum GameCharacter: String {
       case Tumbleweed = "Tumbleweed"
       case PoolBall = "PoolBall"
   }

   func characterSelect(type: GameCharacter) {
       let ud = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
       //Save the current character in User Defaults
       ud.setObject(type.rawValue, forKey: "Current_Character")
       ud.synchronize()
   }

   //When they choose the character:
   characterSelect(.Tumbleweed) //Or Whatever character you have
   ```
2. Game Scene: Load character texture

   ```
   func loadCharacter() {
       let ud = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
       if let currentCharacter = ud.objectForKey("Current_Character") as? String   {
           hero.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: currentCharacter)
       } else {
           hero.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Tumbleweed")
       }
   }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       self.loadCharacter()
   }
   ```